# React handleSubmit return value to dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm attempting to write a very basic MadLibs game to learn more about React.js, I'm running into an issue of where a user enters in a value (a name) and then `handleSubmit` returns it to the dom.  I seem to be missing something here and do not know what it is.

I'd like to do this where a when a user answers one question, they are asked 2 more questions before everything is posted to the DOM.

It's not posting nor working, I get no error to know what's going on, it simply won't write to the DOM

my code is:

```
    class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'start',
      newValue: '',
      submitted: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('submit worked!!!');
    return <div>{this.state.value}</div>;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          marginTop: '50px',
          color: 'white',
          top: '25px',
          position: 'absolute'
        }}
      >

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Name:
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NameForm;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: When you say "I seem to be missing something here" what is the exact nature of the problem? Please post the console log too, thanks.

Comment: what's you question actually? What's the expected outcome?

Comment: where are your questions ?. There should be some other input elements in dom hardcoded with questions or there should be array of questions and when all questions are makred you can post to dom. you can track question index in state.

Comment: apologies, I updated it however here's my question "It's not posting nor working, I get no error to know what's going on, it simply won't write to the DOM"

Comment: That is a statement my friend.

Comment: @sthig, does your code print to the console ?

Comment: @John it does not, the console.log does work with "it worked!!!" but I can't seem to get {this.state.value} to print to the dom

Comment: @sthig, i see now, your not telling react to update the dom, that is why

Comment: @John I see, I am drawing a blank as to do that (I'm new at React and coding in general... uiux background trying to learn).  If you have the answer and you want to post it, happy to give you the vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are binding the wrong thing as this then.

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
```

These mean that your value of **this** will always be the parent Component and not the event.target.value that you are trying to set.

Just remove the lines, and it should work, as **this** should become the caller context (e.g. the input field), which would mean that your **event.target.value** should get and set what is entered properly.

Also, instead of returning on the handleSubmit, you should set what is conditionally rendered inside the render() method, and handle submit should set a state property, like **hasSubmitted**, which you can check in the render to conditionally render a form or something else.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this code is not working, is because you are not telling react to update the virtual DOM. In your function you return JSX,

```
return <div>{this.state.value}</div>;
```

but what is react suppose to do with that ? You have to tell the application what you want to do. It can be done in a few ways (like if you are using redux i would recommend using a reducer), but i would recommend conditional rendering. It would be kinda difficult to write out exactly what you need in the answer box, so here is a link that could probably do a better job explaining then me. If you have any questions, please let me know, if you really need some code examples ill write them out.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('submit worked!!!');
    let toggle = this.state.visable; 
    this.setState({ visable: !toggle });
  }
  render() {
    const divStyle = {
      marginTop: '50px',
      color: 'white',
      top: '25px',
      position: 'absolute'
    };
    let question = null;
    const show = this.state.visable;
    if(show){
      question = <div>{this.state.value}</div> ; 
    }
    return (
      <div>
      <div  style={divStyle}>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Name:
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        </div>
        <div>
          {question}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: ah, I think I understand this.  I have to do something at work but at next break will try this and report back, thank you

Comment: Np, you were close, good job. All you need now is the component, that will be updated when they hit submit,added to your render function. I think the docs do a better job explaining, but like i said if you have questions please let me know.

Comment: thanks, working on it.  It's so frustrating (in a good way), with uiux I have this all mapped out in my head and can just dive in and go... code is very difficult and so slow (once I get something, I got it and I can keep moving).  Wrote a little bit of it out and it's "kinda" working but not there yet.  More in a little over an hour at next break 

(I'm trying to be a better uiux designer for the dev team so I understand their world and can design accordingly for it)

Comment: @sthig, i decided to go ahead to get you started.

Comment: ah, ok that sheds some light on things.  ok more very soon, this makes plenty of sense.  thank you!

Comment: ok I gave this is a shot trying to comprehend everything.  Everything looks to work but `{question}` is still not printing to the DOM, not sure why as it all seems to be in order (console.log is working, no errors or warning).  Is there something in `handleChange` that is supposed to happen as well?

Comment: remove your style tags from the div, and see if you see it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150223/discussion-between-sthig-and-john).